# reading a file into map with list as value

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a file where each row is separated by a '|' delimiter e.g:

```
1|23|1234|car|10
2|12|345|taxi|11
```

where each first value is unique. I want to read it into a map so that first value is the key and the following ones are a list of values for that key.

I have the following implementation, but I'm not sure if my way of locating the delimiter is correct or how to assign the needed value as key.

```
   std::map<int, list<>> sample_map;
   
   

   std::ifstream in("file.txt");
   unsigned sum = 0;
   string line;
   while (getline(in, line)) {
      const char *last = nullptr;
      unsigned col = 0;
      for (char &c : line)
         if (c == '|') {
            ++col;
            if (col == 1) {
               unsigned v;
               from_chars(last, &c, v);
               // assign v to key and rest of the data 
               // as values (excluding delimiter) 
               
               break;
            }
         }
   }
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<const char *>('file.txt')` ==> `"file.txt"`. Does your compiler not complain about that?

Comment: `std::map<int, list<>> sample_map;`  There is nothing inside the template parameters for the list.  Should the list be always strings or should it be a variant of int and string?

Comment: @mch it complained and offered that fix actually

Comment: @JerryJeremiah the data contains both ints and strings, so i wasn't sure how to go about it. but yes, both

Comment: `std::getline` with `|` separator might be handy.

Comment: Are the values on each line always 3 unsigned integers and 1 string?

Comment: @TedLyngmo  yes they are

Comment: the `reinterpret_cast` turns off the compiler's brains and forces it to do what you say no matter how bad the idea is. That a compiler suggested a solution like that is utterly <expletive deleted> insane. What compiler and version, please?

Comment: Anyway, now that I've knocked my indignation down a enough to be rational, the problem was `'file.txt'` is trying to interpret many characters as one character and then using that character as an input to a function expecting a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters. You wanted `std::ifstream in("file.txt");`. Note the double quotes. That gives you a string literal, a null terminated array of characters.

Comment: @user4581301 it's gnu 9.3.0...i see. thanks.

Comment: Use a struct to model the record (text line).  It will simplify your program.  See my answer.

Comment: If you don't want a struct but just want a `map<int,list<>>`  you can do it this way: https://onlinegdb.com/07fPfi5Sl

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a `struct` or `class` to **model** the input row (record):

```
struct Record  
{  
    int id;
    int column2;
    int column3;  
    int name;  
    int last_column;
    // Overload operator >> for this record.
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    char separator;  
    input >> r.id;
    input >> separator;
    input >> r.column2; input >> separator;
    input >> r.column3; input >> separator;
    std::getline(input, r.name, '|');
    input >> r.last_column;
    input.ignore(100000, '\n'); // Reset to next line.  
    return input;
}
```

Your input code could look like this:

```
std::map<int, Record> database;
Record r;
int id;
while (in >> r)
{
  id = r.id;
  database[id] = r;
}
```

There is a duplication of the ID in this implementation, but it uses the ID field as a key and you have your ID field in the record if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a `struct` to keep the data and to overload `operator>>` to help with the input. I've also added a mini-struct to eat up the delimiters `|` and `\n` - which could be done purely with `std::getline` but you'd then need to convert the integers so I decided to use the existing `operator>>` to read integers from the  stream.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

//---------------------------------- a class to eat a delimiter
struct eat { char ch; };

// eat the expected character or set the stream in a failed state:
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const eat& e) {
    if(is.peek() == e.ch) is.ignore();
    else is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    return is;
}
//----------------------------------

struct data {    // the data the key in your map will map to
    unsigned a;
    unsigned b;
    std::string c;
    unsigned d;
};

// read one `data` from the stream:
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, data& d) {
    eat e{'|'}; // used to eat up `|`
    return std::getline(is >> d.a >> e >> d.b >> e, d.c, '|') >> d.d >> eat{'\n'};
}

// print one `data`
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const data& d) {
    return os << d.a << '|' << d.b << '|' << d.c << '|' << d.d << '\n';
}
```

Reading the map from the file and printing it:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    if(std::ifstream in("file.txt"); in) {

        std::map<int, data> m;

        int key;
        data d;

        // read one key and one `data` until that fails:
        while(in >> key >> eat{'|'} >> d) {
            m[key] = std::move(d);          // put it in the map
        }

        // print the result:
        for(auto&[k, v] : m) {
            std::cout << k << '|' << v;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4oevefqhq)